# NEW popcorn-time.se Beta 3.2 installation - ./configure not found

Tags: software-installation, tar, beta

Currently the Popcorn-time tar.gz available on the site is version 3.2 I have followed a few guides on here, youtube.

there is only 4 files located in the tar.gz

```
libffmpegsumo.so
nw.pak
package.nw
Popcorn-time
```

I followed askubuntu/questions/675526/ and /25961/

and a couple half witted youtube videos.

I did

I navigated to the download folder with cd then typed

```
tar xvzf Popcorn-Time-linux32.tar.gz

./configure
```

then got the following error

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the file found here:

```
http://www.time4popcorn.eu/Popcorn-Time-linux64.0.3.1.tar.gz
```

The commands for this are ...

```
tar xvzf Popcorn-Time-linux32.tar.gz
./Popcorn-Time
```

No need to "configure" anything; you get the software in such a manner you can use it immediately.

---

If you want a more Debian method; there is a PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install popcorn-time
```

This will have you install the latest version (currently seems to be 0.3.2)